# How do I import ONIX XML into Magento?

Tags: import, php, xml

I need to get ONIX data to my Magento ebook store. I could convert it into a format that Magento understands (i.e. CSV) and then use the default import. But at times the a single feed can have a few new books, a few updates. This can’t be achieved by the default Magento import. Do you guys have any suggestions about how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is well-formed, you could create a script that lives outside of Magento to handle this using [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/simplexml). The script would take your XML file, process it to an array or object, loop over that data, and use the Magento core code to create a new product or find and update products for each item processed. You could either run this script manually or use a Cron job to run it at a defined interval.